# Parse a large text file and store it in a tree (Binary or AVL) using C++

Tags: c++

I am doing an assignment, in which I have a large text file (1gb). I am supposed to parse this text file and store it in a tree for some operations. The problem I am facing is the time it takes to completely parse the whole file. It takes about 40 min to completely parse the file. Can anyone please show me how to do it efficiently in a few minutes?
My code is

```
int main()
{
FILE * file=fopen("data.txt","r");
char line[1000];
char *token;

while(fgets(line,1000,file)!=NULL) 
{
    token=strtok(line,"     ");
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<token<<endl;
        token=strtok(NULL,"     ");
    }
}

fclose(file);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure what's taking time is the parsing and not the printing?

Comment: You may be running into [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29) if you don't have enough memory available.

Comment: Time how long it takes to run if you direct stdout to a file rather than the screen i.e. `program > output.txt`

Comment: Better still, redirect it nowhere: `program > /dev/null` (or `program > nul` on windows).

Comment: Try taking out the `endl`.  That forces a completely unnecessary output flush, which I'm thinking accounts for almost all of the time, six characters per word, 1 gig, 167M words, 167M flushes.

Also call `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would guess that printing the tokens is the biggest time sink. Try this instead and see if it runs faster:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::ifstream in("data.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
    for (std::string token; in >> token; ) {
        if (++count / 100000 == 0) {
            std::cout << "read " << count << " tokens\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "read " << count << " tokens\n";
}
```